# Temporary creation of html div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I am trying to create div's on demand which then timeout and are then hidden and removed from the dom. 
The display property of "load_bar" is set to none so that I can use the last selector to get a reference to the instance I have just created. 
It is important that this solution can create several div's which are running on their own timeout clock

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var t = Math.random()*20;
        alert(t);
        var destination = $('input').val();
        $('#holding_pen').append('<div class="load_bar">'+destination+'</div>');
        $('.load_bar:last').show().delay(t).hide().remove();
    });
});
```

Every thing works to create divs when I remove `.delay().hide().remove();`
However when I add this the div is not shown at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create proper elements, that way you'll have a reference to the element within the function:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var t           = (Math.random()*20)*1000,
            destination = $('input').val(),
            div         = $('<div />', {'class':'load_bar', text: destination});

        $('#holding_pen').append(div);
        div.show(1).delay(t).hide(1, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Also, `hide()` and `show()` does not work with the animation queue and subsequently not with `delay()` ***unless*** a duration is given, and that's why the element is never shown, `delay()` doesn't work and the element is hidden right away.

**EDIT:**

Also, `remove()` is not an animated method, so it doesn't work with `delay()`, but `hide()` a useful callback for that, see edited code above.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/taLRy/)

Comment: If I add short durations to my show and hide function then it does work however when I substitute the code for what you have written above it doesn't work. I haven't seen multiple declaration of variable before and am wondering if it is a problem to create and use destination at the same time

Comment: @PeterSaxton - edited the answer, see if that works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `delay` is used to stop jQuery animation queue, which both `show` and `hide` do not use. Therefore your div is being shown and them immediately hidden. Use `setTimeout` instead:

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var destination = $('input').val();
    $('#holding_pen').append('<div class="load_bar">'+destination+'</div>');
    $('.load_bar:last').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.load_bar:last').hide();
    }, Math.random() * 20 * 1000); // * 1000 = seconds
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9dH2C/)

Answer (score 0):

The delay() function only applies to actions queued on the element.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var t = Math.random()*20;
        alert(t);
        var destination = $('input').val();
        $('#holding_pen').append('<div class="load_bar">'+destination+'</div>');
        $('.load_bar:last').show().delay(t).queue(function( nxt ) {
            $(this).hide().remove();
            nxt(); // continue the queue
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var t = Math.random()*20;
        alert(t);
        var destination = $('input').val();
        $('#holding_pen').innerHTML='<div class="load_bar">'+destination+'</div>';

    });
});
```